# How use SSL between geth nodes communication?

Tags: go-ethereum, poa

I have a poa network contains 4 nodes, I want to secure the communication between those nodes, is it possible using SSL and reverse proxy ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You can check out this article for other possible ways to secure your nodes
https://medium.com/coinmonks/securing-your-ethereum-nodes-from-hackers-8b7d5bac8986

Comment: I'm not asking about securing the http rpc, I want to secure the communication between nodes (when they sync transactions and blocks)